# Cannot access row[1] using arcpy.da.SearchCursor

Tags: arcpy, cursor, indexerror

My code creates a dissolved feature class with 2 rows. For some reason I am unable to access the 2nd row using the following code:

```
fcCount = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
print(fc) #2
def getrowValues():
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "Field") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            print(row[0]) #Prints value
            print(row[1]) #IndexError: tuple index out of range
rowValues = getrowValues()
```

I looked at the examples [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000/), but I was unable to find the source of error.

Edit: This accomplished what i was trying to achieve:

```
def getrowValues():
    val =[]
    rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, fields= "Field")
    for row in rows:
        val.append(row.getValue("Field"))
    if val[0] == val[1]:
        return val[0]
    else:
        return ' & '.join(val)
```

Answer (score 3):

Comment out the second print row

```
fcCount = arcpy.GetCount_management(fc)
print(fc) #2
def getrowValues():
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, "Field") as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            print(row[0]) #Prints value
            #print(row[1]) #IndexError: tuple index out of range
rowValues = getrowValues()
```

The second time you call print (row[1]), you are asking it to print a second attribute field. Since you only specified one field, "Field", which would be [0], there is no field [1].

Comment: beat me by seconds :)

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to compare the first and second row values for that particular field. I updated my original post with my solution. I wasn't clear on the different searchcursor functions and how to use them.